# Merging json and csv using topojson

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, merge, topojson

I realize that there are a few examples of this, but I wasn't having any luck actually getting the properties working, so I figure I'd ask in this specific example. I want to take the properties from my csv, and append it to the json file through the common id.

along the lines of

```
topojson -o final.json -e waste.csv -p population=population -p waste=waste, -p country=country -- world.json
```

my world.json file is as follows (From Mike Bostock)

```
{"type":"Topology",
"objects":{"countries":
        {"type":"GeometryCollection","bbox":[-179.99999999999997,-90.00000000000003,180.00000000000014,83.64513000000001],
         "geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","id":4,"arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4,5]]},
                       {"type":"MultiPolygon","id":24,"arcs":[[[6,7,8,9]],[[10,11,12]]]},
                       {"type":"Polygon","id":8,"arcs":[[13,14,15,16,17]]},{"type":"Polygon","id":784,"arcs":[[18,19,20,21,22]]}
```

And the following is my waste.csv:

```
id,country,income,region,population,wpc,waste,future_pop,future_urban_pop,future_wpc,future_waste,organic,paper,plastic,glass,metal,other
8,Albania,LMI,ECA,"1,418,524",0.77,"1,088","3,488,000","2,006,000",1.2,"2,407",38,10,8,5,5,34
12,Algeria,LMI,MENA,"19,225,335",1.21,"23,288","42,882,000","31,778,000",1.45,"46,078",70,10,5,1,2,12
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know , --id-property which you are specifying should be a property

> --id-property name of feature property to promote to geometry id.By default, topojson retains the id attribute of input features. If you wish to promote a property to the feature ID as part of the conversion to TopoJSON, use the --id-property argument.

```
    {"type":"Topology",
  "objects":{"countries":
    {"type":"GeometryCollection","bbox":[-179.99999999999997,-90.00000000000003,180.00000000000014,83.64513000000001],
     "geometries":[{"type":"Polygon",properties:{"id":4},"arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4,5]]},
                   {"type":"MultiPolygon",properties:{"id":24},"arcs":[[[6,7,8,9]],[[10,11,12]]]},
                   {"type":"Polygon",properties:{"id":8},"arcs":[[13,14,15,16,17]]},{"type":"Polygon","id":784,"arcs":[[18,19,20,21,22]]}
```

topojson -o final.json -e waste.csv  --id-property=+id,+id -p population=population -p waste=waste, -p country=country -- world.json

Comment: So, what you're saying it I should be doing something more along the lines of topojson -o final.json -e waste.csv -p population=population , waste=waste -- world.json ?

Comment: What I am saying is id must be a property .I updated the answer.Check this